# Merge multiple projects into single project TFS/ADO

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools, azure-migrate, vsts-sync-migrator

I was exploring following GitHub page to understand the migration and merge of projects from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services

https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools

I see in the documentation, the following feature was mentioned. But, unfortunately, I could not see any relevant documentation for the same. Please help with this.

**Merge many projects into a single project**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: edited the description with more detail

Answer (score 1):

You do it through the configuration file as part of the tool. It requires tinkering and trial and error to get it working but is a very useful. In the config file you state a source and a target and the amend the parama you want and then run the tool. It not very well documented though but is still a powerful tool.